# Text boxes uses UIDatePicker

Tags: xcode, swift, uidatepicker

I am creating an app in Xcode using swift and I have a text box that uses UIDatePicker, but now all of my other text boxes are using this date picker when I want them to be just a number pad. Any help is much appreciated. The text box I want to be UIDatePicker is called "StartDate", but I have others that need to be a number pad. I am still a beginner with Swift and XCode, but like I said all help is much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

weak var StartDate: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    textField.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
    StartDate.text = formatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

// Code to close keyboard that can be used throughout the app
func closeKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

// Close keyboard on touch anywhere else
  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    closeKeyboard()}


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    StartDate.delegate = self
}

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == StartDate {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        textField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    }else {
        //do stuff with the rest of the textFields
    }
}
```